# Visual Studio 2015 CTP broken after latest Windows 10 update 9860?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Upon upgrading to Windows 10 build 9860, the latest Visual Studio 14 preview starting showing this error on startup:

> The 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.EditorPackage' package did not load correctly.

[image]

Things didn’t get any better when you try to do anything in the shiny new IDE.. For example, here’s what happens when creating a new C# Console project:

```
Object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.Lazy'1+Boxed[Microsoft.VisualSstudio.Text.IExtensionErrorHandler]]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.Lazy'1[Microsoft.Text.IExtensionErrorHandler]]'.
```

[image]

I wasn't going to ask a question here until I saw it happen on more than one machine today.. Once I reproduced it, I figured it was worth posting here...

Comment: i don't know why in the world someone downvoted this but i upvoted it to even it out. This is good to know since i just had the same exact thing happen to me

Comment: Thanks. I felt like I had done something stupid by trying to help people out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fortunately, I found that repairing Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 14 CTP in Add/Remove Programs seems to fix the problem.. You will get the following error at the end of the repair procedure, but at least I’m able to use Visual Studio again afterwards:

[image]

Comment: I went through this same process, this answer should be “accepted” ;-).